# Group and term query combination in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene

I am new to Lucene and I wanted I wanted to filter my search result based on 3 criterion:

1. value of field `document_type` should be `Product`
2. value of field `brand_id` should be 4
3. value of field `family_id` should be all of the values from (121, 232, 343)

So what I basically want is to have combinations like following in the search result:

1. `document_type:Product AND brand_id:4 AND family_id:121`
2. `document_type:Product AND brand_id:4 AND family_id:232`
3. `document_type:Product AND brand_id:4 AND family_id:343`

I thought `document_type:Product AND brand_id:4 AND family_id:(121 232 343)` should do the trick but while parsing this query standard analyzer makes `Product` to even when while indexing field `document_type` for value `Product` was set to `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` and `Field.Store.YES`.

I was wondering if it is possible to create a boolean query by combining 3 possible queries for the given 3 cases.

I am quite new with Lucene, could someone help me with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query.combine(Query[]) worked like a charm for the given situation.
```

The documentation for the given method is available [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/core/index.html).

The query turned out to be like following once the combine was applied:

```
(+document_type:Product +brand_id:4 +family_id:121) (+document_type:Product +brand_id:4 +family_id:232) (+document_type:Product +brand_id:4 +family_id:343)
```

Thanks.